# Perl to Java translation

Tags: java, perl

I'm wondering if someone could help explain what is going on in the following code snippet, as I'm trying to translate to Java, but my Perl knowledge is tiny.

```
sub burble {
    my $cw = "%START%";
    my $sentence;
    my $nw;
    my ( $score, $s, $roll );
    while ( $cw ne "." )    # while we're not at the end
                            # of the sentence yet
    {
        $score = 0;

        # get total score to randomise within
        foreach $s ( values %{ $dict{$cw} } ) {
            $score += $s;
        }

        # now get a random number within that
        $roll  = int( rand() * $score );
        $score = 0;
        foreach $nw ( keys %{ $dict{$cw} } ) {
            $score += ${ $dict{$cw} }{$nw};
            if ( $score > $roll )    # chosen a word
            {
                $sentence .= "$nw " unless $nw eq ".";
                $cw = $nw;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    return $sentence;
}
```

Comment: A quick glance, this appears to build a [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). If this is the best way to do this in java is debatable.

Comment: Where is the definition of %dict?

Comment: Yes it is a Markov chain. The original script can be found here http://www.lab6.com/old/niall-perl.html

Comment: what part of the perl are you struggling to understand, so we can help you through it.

Comment: Beginning at the line foreach $s (values %{$dict{$cw}}) until the end. I don't quite understand how it's getting the score or lines like ${$dict{$cw}}{$nw} - the array syntax is throwing me off a bit.

Comment: dict in perl is a hashtable where keys are strings and values are another hashtable where keys are string and values are integers.  In java this is: Map<String, Map<String, int>> map.  ${$dict{$cw}}{$nw} is equivalent to int score = map.get(cw).get(nw);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach $s (values %{$dict{$cw}}) {
    $score += $s;
}
```

is like

```
Map<String, Map<String, int>> dict = ...;
...
int score;
Map<String, int> mcw = dict.get( cw );

for ( mcw.values() : int s) {
    score += s;
}
```

And

```
foreach $nw (keys %{$dict{$cw}})
```

is like

```
KEY_LOOP:
for ( mcw.keys() : String nw ) {
    ...
}
```

Finally,

```
if ($score > $roll) # chosen a word
{
    $sentence .= "$nw " unless $nw eq ".";
    $cw = $nw;
    last;
}
```

is like:

```
if ( score > roll ) { // a break case
   if ( !nw.equals( "." )) { 
       sentence = sentence + nw + " ";
   }
   cw       = nw
   break KEY_LOOP;
}
```